# How to make a specific thread to sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep

I have 9 threads that do some calculations . I want to make one of them , or more , to go to sleep .

The code :

```
public class CalcArray 
{
    private static int[] m_array = null;
    private static int sum = 0;
    private final static int MAX_VALUE = 80;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public static void putValues()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE ; i++)
        {
            m_array[i] = 1;
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        m_array = new int[80];
        putValues();
        int lowBound = 0;
        int upperBound = 9;

        Thready[] threadsArray = new Thready[10]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < 8 ; j++)
        {
            threadsArray[j] = new Thready(lowBound , upperBound);
            lowBound += 10;
            upperBound += 10;
        }

        // start the threads

        for (int q = 0; q < 8; q++)
        {
            if (q == 5)
            {
                // make the thread with #5 to take a nap
                // Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            threadsArray[q].run();
        }

        System.out.println("Main Thread is done!");
        System.out.println(sum);

    }


    /**
     * 
     * @author X
     *
     */
    public static class Thready implements Runnable 
    {
        int lower = 0;
        int upper = 0;

        public Thready(int paramLower , int paramUpper)
        {
            lower = paramLower;
            upper = paramUpper;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            synchronized(m_array)
            {
                for (int i = lower ; i <= upper ; i++)
                {
                    sum += m_array[i];
                }

                System.out.println("The current value is :" + sum);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

I want to make thread number #5 to take a nap . If I use `Thread.sleep(3000);` it would cause the Main Thread to go to sleep . So how can I tell thread #5 to go to sleep ?

Comment: You can't make another thread sleep. You can only make the current thread sleep.

Comment: The Thread can only make itself sleep. You need to pass it a signal somehow (implemented in your own code).

Comment: There may be better ways to achieve what you need. What do you actually need to achieve?

Comment: Don't start the Thread with run() method, it executes ONLY run method from this Thread and then closes. use start() instead.

Comment: There is only one thread in your example... @Niemand there are no threads in the example, only Runnables, so they can only be run...

Comment: You are of course right, I mistook Thready for Thread. He should use something like new Thread(new Thready()).start();

Comment: *You* write the code that all the threads run. Any time you feel the need to *make* another thread do something, that just means you didn't code it to do what you actually wanted it to do. The solution is to fix the code so the thread does what you want so you don't need to "reach in" and force it to do the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
public class Test 
{
    private static int[] m_array = null;
    private static int sum = 0;
    private final static int MAX_VALUE = 80;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public static void putValues()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE ; i++)
        {
            m_array[i] = 1;
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        m_array = new int[80];
        putValues();
        int lowBound = 0;
        int upperBound = 9;

        Thready[] threadsArray = new Thready[10]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < 8 ; j++)
        {
            threadsArray[j] = new Thready(j, lowBound , upperBound);
            lowBound += 10;
            upperBound += 10;
        }

        // start the threads

        for (int q = 0; q < 8; q++)
        {
            if (q == 5)
            {
                threadsArray[q].snooze(3000);
                // make the thread with #5 to take a nap
                // Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            (new Thread(threadsArray[q])).start();
        }

        System.out.println("Main Thread is done!");
        System.out.println(sum);

    }


    /**
     * 
     * @author X
     *
     */
    public static class Thready implements Runnable 
    {
        int lower = 0;
        int upper = 0;
        int threadNum = 0;

        public Thready(int threadNum, int paramLower , int paramUpper)
        {
            this.threadNum = threadNum;
            lower = paramLower;
            upper = paramUpper;
        }

        public void snooze(long howlong) throws InterruptedException
        {
            System.out.println("Thread "+threadNum+": Taking a nap of "+howlong+" millis.");
            Thread.sleep(howlong);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            synchronized(m_array)
            {
                for (int i = lower ; i <= upper ; i++)
                {
                    sum += m_array[i];
                }

                System.out.println("Thread "+threadNum+": The current value is :" + sum);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Lovely . I tried to avoid that , I thought there's some built-in method , but we'll manage :) . thanks .